# Child Use Different Layout From the Parent

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In Nuxt How To use Difrrent Layout From The Parent

Ex.
**_profile 

  page a

  page b**
Profile Use Layout A
so Automaticallay Page a and Page b use layout a
but i want to use layout B in page a and page b

Answer (score 0):

> How To use Difrrent Layout From The Parent

First, create a new layout B inside `layouts` folder like:

**layoutb.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="layoutb">
    <Nuxt />
  </div>
</template>
```

Next, we can use the `layout` key in your pages components (`pagea.vue` & `pagea.vue`) to define which layout to use:

**pagea.vue**

```
export default {
  layout: 'layoutb',
  ...
}
```

**pageb.vue**

```
export default {
  layout: 'layoutb',
  ...
}
```

Now you will see page a and page b using layout B instead of layout A.